# Examples for AC circuit analysis with AC voltage source in parallel with DC current source?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Where can I find examples of AC analysis of circuits with AC voltage source in parallel with DC current source and resistors? I could only find examples involving capacitors and inductors.

Comment: There are three types of analysis of these type of circuits:  DC analysis, steady state AC analysis and the transient analysis for the "stuff" in-between.  Start with a simple RL circuit with a switch if you need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for "real" examples of such circuits. One class of circuits having both ac and dc sources could be ac amplifiers. For instance, the input stage of a simple [mic pre-amp circuit](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Audio/tl071_mic.png) has an ac source (the mic) in parallel with thevenin DC source created by the the two 47k voltage divider resistor.

[image: Simple mic preamp]